# Which openCv function can be used to compute BEV perspective transformation given a point coordinates and the camera extrinsics/intrinsics?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I have the `3x3` `intrinsics` and `4x3` `extrinsics` matrices for my camera obtained via `cv2.calibrateCamera()`

Now I want to use these paramenters to compute the `BEV (Bird Eye View)` transformation for any given coordinates in a frame obtained from the camera.

Which `openCv` function can be used to compute the `BEV` perspective transformation for given point coordinates and the camera `extrinsics` and/or `intrinsics` `3x3 matrices`?

I found something very related in the following post: https://deepnote.com/article/social-distancing-detector/ based on https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/ ,

they are using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` to get a `3X3 matrix`, but I don't know whether this matrix represents the `intrinsics`, the `extrinsecs` or something else. Then they are transforming the list of points using such matrix in the following way:

```
#Assuming list_downoids is the list of points to be transformed and matrix is the one obtained above
list_points_to_detect = np.float32(list_downoids).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
transformed_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(list_points_to_detect, matrix)
```

I really need to know if I can use this `cv2.perspectiveTransform` function to compute the transformation or if there's another better way to do this using the `extrinsics`, the `intrinsics` or both, without having to reuse the frame, since I already have the detected/selected coordinates saved in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep investigation, I found out a good solution:

The `projection matrix` is a multiplication between the`extrinsic` and the `intrinsic` camera matrices

- https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-homography-for-pose-estimation-in-opencv-a7215f260fdd
- Since the `extrinsic` is a `4x3` matrix and the `intrinsec` is a `3x3` matrix, but we need the `projection matrix` to be a `3x3` matrix, then we need to convert the `extrinsic` into `3x3` before performing the multiplication.

`cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` gives us the `Projection Matrix` when we don't have the camera params:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hands-on-application-of-homography-ipm-18d9e47c152f

`cv2.warpPerspective()` transforms the image itsef.

For the problem above we don't need these two functions since we already have the `extrinsics`, the `intrinsecs` and the coordinates of the points in the image.

Considering the presented above, I wrote a function to transform into `BEV` a list o points `list_x_y` given the `intrinsics` and the `extrinsics`:

```
    def compute_point_perspective_transformation(intrinsics, extrinsics, point_x_y):
    """Auxiliary function to project a specific point to BEV
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        intrinsics (array)     : The camera intrinsics matrix
        extrinsics (array)     : The camera extrinsics matrix
        point_x_y (tuple[x,y]) : The coordinates of the point to be projected to BEV
        
        Returns
        ----------
        tuple[x,y] : the projection of the point
    """
        # Using the camera calibration for Bird Eye View
        intrinsics_matrix = np.array(intrinsics, dtype='float32')
        #In the intrinsics we have parameters such as focal length and the principal point

        extrinsics_matrix = np.array(extrinsics, dtype='float32')
        #The extrinsic matrix stores the position of the camera in global space
        #The 1st 3 columns represents the rotation matrix and the last is a translation vector
        extrinsics = extrinsics[:, [0, 1, 3]]

        #We removed the 3rd column of the extrinsics because it represents the z coordinate (0)
        projection_matrix = np.matmul(intrinsics_matrix, extrinsics_matrix)

        # Compute the new coordinates of our points - cv2.perspectiveTransform expects shape 3
        list_points_to_detect = np.array([[point_x_y]], dtype=np.float32)
        transformed_points = cv2.perspectiveTransform(list_points_to_detect, projection_matrix)
        return transformed_points[0][0][0], transformed_points[0][0][1]
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is an answer to your question?(the part after "considering the presented above") I see that you are returning parts of the perspective transform matrix but How does this answer the "compute the BEV perspective transformation for given point coordinates " question?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is : it is impossible to compute a BEV of a scene if you do not have distance-related information about the pixels of your image.

Think about it : imagine you have the picture of a vertical screen : the Bird's Eye View would then be a line. Now say that this screen is displaying the image of a landscape and that the picture of this screen is indistinguishable from a picture of the landscape itself. The BEV would still be a line (a colorful one though).

Now, imagine you have the exactly the same picture, but this time it's not a picture of a screen but of the landscape. Then, the Bird's Eye View is **not** a line and is closer to what we usually imagine a BEV to be.

Finally, let me state that OpenCV has no way to know if your picture is describing a plane of something else (even given camera parameters), therefore, it **cannot** compute the BEV of your scene. The function `cv2.perspectiveTransform` needs you to pass it a *homography* matrix (you may obtain one using `cv2.findHomography()`, but you will need some distance information about your image as well).

Sorry about the negative answer, but there's no way to solve your problem given only the intrinsic and extrinsic calibration matrices of the camera.

Comment: Thanks for your response Joseph. What if I additionally provide the frame and the coordinates, of the points in the referred frame, I want to project?

Comment: If you have 3D coordinates of at least 3 points (I think you need only three, but the more, the better), then you should be able to do it using `cv2.findHomography`. It gets little technical there so I would advise you to look for tutorials. I remember having found some very interesting ones out there :)

Comment: For instance if your picture represents an oblique plane (I considerr roads to be sufficiently plane-like for this) I think this tutorial will help you : https://www.learnopencv.com/tag/findhomography/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I have `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` for each point. I think that can work.

Comment: You're welcome ! Good luck ! (By the way, I would appreciate a lot if you could accept my answer, thanks !) :)

Comment: Alright. Sounds good. Could you please mark one of my comments on the top arrow?

Comment: a perspective transform needs four point pairs (four points in each of both views). I would have answered YES because if you understand "bird's eye view" to be a plane-to-plane transformation, getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective will work. things only break down if you try to warp a picture of a 3D scene that isn't a flat plane. it is reasonable to assume that "BEV" meant mapping a plane.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do you mean by "a picture of a 3D scene that isn't a flat plane"?

Comment: say you're flying in a plane and you take pictures of the ground. you fly over farms in Kansas. flat as a pancake. then you fly over Manhattan. skyscrapers. if you take a picture of those from an angle, you won't see just the rooves but also the sides of the skyscrapers. there's no way to warp the image to get a true top-down view (only rooves).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the camera model, an off the shelf (but not complete) solution would be to use the `getTopViewOfImage` [function from the camera transform library](https://cameratransform.readthedocs.io/en/latest/camera.html#cameratransform.Camera.getTopViewOfImage)